# How can the following proof of the given propositions be made?

Tags: complex-analysis

Please explain in detail, thank you

1.- Let $M_{2\times 2}$ be the set of matrices of dimension $2\times 2$. Determine whether the following proposition is true or false and proves your claim: there is an injective function $f: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow M_{2\times 2}$  such that $f(zw)=f(z)f(w)$.

2.- Determine if the following statement is true or false and prove your claim: yes $p(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients and $p(\alpha)=0$, then $p(\overline{\alpha})=0$.

Comment: Hints. (1) What is a natural copy of $\mathbb{C}$ inside $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$? If they are real matrices, you have to think a little harder... but you’re basically embedding the complex numbers inside $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ — a “representation” if you will (2) Complex conjugation is a homomorphism that fixes the real numbers

Comment: Please show your own efforts and explain where it is you are running into trouble, thank you.